# Getting WFS data from Geoserver into leaflet

Tags: geoserver, wfs, leaflet

I'm trying to use a ajax call to load WFS data from geoserver into a GeoJson layer in leaflet.

When I do the following message in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=…rmat=text/javascript&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:loadGeoJson. 
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I know that if you are trying to load wfs into OpenLayers you need a proxy.cgi as per this thread: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost: /geoserver/wfs. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38855/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-http-localhost-geoserver-wfs-origin-http-local)

That script seems to relate only to OpenLayers. 
My question is can I use this for leaflet and if not how to I get the wfs data? There must be a way round this problem but I can't see anything in the main documentation and I've searched almost exhausted my searching elsewhere.

---

I have added my script for the leaflet page...

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([50.370, -4.14], 14);


var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/a8ed148d84c2438ba62c2742cac051ae/33356/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery Â© <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var myLayer = new L.geoJson(null,{
onEachFeature: function 
(feature, layer) 
{layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.comment);} 
}).addTo(map);


function loadGeoJson(data) {myLayer.addData(data); 
}

var geoJsonUrl = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:masts&srsName=EPSG:4326&format=text/javascript&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:loadGeoJson";
$.ajax({ 
        url: geoJsonUrl, 
        dataType: 'jsonp' 
});
```

and the httpd.conf...

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/foo.log".
#
# NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
# instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
# If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which Apache.exe is located
# will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
# an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
# at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
# httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80



#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php5apache2_2.dll"

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin admin@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.11
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web
<Location /geoserver>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://localhost/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>


#
# Configure the proxy module of Apache
#
ProxyRequests On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyStatus On

    Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While you can set up a proxy with your webserver, there is an easier way.

First, [enable JSONP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57494/geoserver-2-3-how-to-enable-jsonp) in GeoServer.

Then form your data requests like this:

```
var owsrootUrl = 'https://<GEOSERVER URL - CHANGEME>/geoserver/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '2.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : '<WORKSPACE:LAYERNAME - CHANGEME>',
    outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);

var WFSLayer = null;
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
        WFSLayer = L.geoJson(response, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return {
                    stroke: false,
                    fillColor: 'FFFFFF',
                    fillOpacity: 0
                };
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                layer.bindPopup("Popup text, access attributes with feature.properties.ATTRIBUTE_NAME"
                    ,popupOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }
});
```

This has the additional advantage on working on your test server, as it avoids cross site scripting issues due to the use of JSONP (quoted json objects, from my understanding).

For an example of this in action, see these two maps:

- https://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/glenorchy_mtbp.html
- https://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/stormwater.html

Code [here](https://github.com/gccgisteam/maps-website) (for posterity).

By the way, I use nginx for the webserver and have the proxy stuff working. If you would like to know how please let me know and I'll edit something in here.

EDIT: another way of getting rid of this error is [enabling CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) in either Tomcat (or Jetty, maybe?) or your reverse proxy.

Comment: is it possible to bring multiple wfs layers into the map using this method.

Comment: Hi Matt, yes it is. I think you can have multiple 'typeName' workspace:layer pairs, separated by a comma. In that 'code here' link above, look at the undergroundassets file, that has multiple layers getting queried (though it is a bit complex, as they are dynamic).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've been studying your site quite a bit recently and really like what you've done. From what I can see though you use WMS to bring multiple layers into to the map and then a loop over the WFS layers to bring the popup info, etc. 

I've also been experimenting with the leaflet-ajax and leaflet-wfst plugins - both of which are useful.

Comment: Hi @MattT, glad you like it! It (the WMS/WFS combo) is the best way to get performance and interactivity at scale, aside from MapBox/CartoDB's magic vector tiling. I messed around with WFS-T some time ago, but it wasn't finished (and I didn't have time to finish it). Does it work now? And Leaflet Ajax is fine, I guess that'll do a new query for each pan? I've got a generic interface here that you can point at a GeoServer endpoint and load all the layers in: https://github.com/alexgleith/bootleaf_gs - what it needs is better 'onclick' function, that puts returned data into a nice popover.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of the library used, web browsers won't allow loading Ajax content from another port (in this case 8080), even from the same domain. The easiest way to fix this is to set up mod_proxy in Apache webserver (sample configuration: [mod_proxy geoserver Gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobandresen/1004676)), which allows to redirect all GeoServer-related traffic to port 80 and thus no Access-Control-Allow-Origin restrictions will apply.

Comment: Michal - I have added my httpd.conf above now. I have loaded the proxy modules and added proxy text at the bottom. Do I need to include <IfModule ...>?

Comment: Yes, it is better to have the <IfModule mod_proxy.c> directive. Can you successfully reach the GeoServer administrative console on address http://localhost/geoserver using the configuration above? If yes, OGC services should work as well.

Comment: If have added your script to the to http.conf tagged it with <If Module proxy_module> and I can now view localhost/geoserver and do not get the XMLHttpRequest cannot load in my console. However, the data is still not loading into the map. This could be a geoserver issue so I set up another post. Thanks, Matt

Comment: Geoserver supports JSONP out of the box which naturally solves this problem, so I'm not sure how setting up a Apache proxy is the "easiest" way to do this.

Comment: I agree with @TravisWebb. See my alternate answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the appropriate answer, but I wanted to point out that setting up the proxying in nginx is very easy.

Let's say Geoserver is running on port 8080, and your web server (nginx) is running on port 80. It's as simple as adding:

```
location /geoserver {
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

to your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` (or whatever). Now you can send your JSON calls to port 80, and experience no more cross-origin scripting issues.

It would be much trickier if geoserver didn't conveniently have a URL structure which begins "`/geoserver`".

(It's a personal question whether configuring Nginx or modifying your Javascript is "easier"... This arrangement also means one less port that needs to be opened in your firewall.)

Comment: Good answer. The other option is using JSONP from GeoServer, which requires that option to be enabled in the XML file for GeoServer.

Answer (score -2):

```
// load data from geoJSON url

{% for img in images %}
    var geojson_data = 'http://127.0.0.1:7500/all_data/Lorry Tyres'
  $.getJSON(geojson_data,function(data){
    // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
  });
```