# Geoserver popups in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet, popup

I've got a simple Leaflet map with a basemap and one map-layer coming from my own hosted GeoServer.

I made the layers show up nicely in a map.

Now I want to add popups on the point layer showing information stored in MapService.

I couldn't find too much information about that topic.

There's one link to a working example but the link seems to be broken. I found another example which I addopted. You can see it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tnfp82c/). I'd like to display the content of the name field in the attribute table but nothing happens when the user clicks the map.

Any idea?

Comment: You just need to search for example of sending GetFeatureInfo requests to GeoServer. Google is your friend here.

Comment: Well, I'm not really good at writing things like that! Would you mind to help me a bit? Thanks

Comment: I've had luck with this in the past: https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938

Comment: Thanks. Okay, now I can see that it's sending a request but it does not show any popup in the map. Do I have to add code to my index.html? I took the code as provided in the link above. If you want I can put into a JSFiddle. Any idea?

Comment: I get HTTP 400 errors when I click the map in your fiddle. Are you sure your built URL is correct?

Comment: That was a good hint. I updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tnfp82c/3/). It now sends the right request. But still does not display it on the map. What else do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your jsfiddle is that you try to do a Cross-Domain-Request that gets blocked due to the Same-Origin-Policy.

---

[image]

---

I could imagine that this is the same Problem on your server. If you host your Leaflet-App on Port 80 and try to get the Feature-Info from port 8080 this will be blocked.
You can solve this problem by making your geoserver available on port 80,too or by using a proxy-file.

The first option would be less effort, so perhaps you could try this first.

Here you'll find more information: 
[Getting WFS data from Geoserver into leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64406/getting-wfs-data-from-geoserver-into-leaflet/107393#107393)
https://gist.github.com/jacobandresen/1004676

The other option would be to set up a proxy-file (php-file for example) and perhaps also use L.TileLayer.BetterWMS ( https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938 ) which works,too:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the cross-domain later (eventhough I think my webserver uses port 4711 and my geoserver 8080, so probably won't be a problem in production environment).
I got a working map with popups using the BetterWMS you cited above. Now my question: As you can see in the screenshot the popup shows all available information. Would it be possible to define, let's says, to display infor from the "name" field only? thanks and BR

Comment: Would it be possible to show a vertical instead of a horizontal list in the popup? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can use Freemarker-Templates (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) or use "info_format=application/json" and iterate trough the response ( http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo )

Comment: Thank you very much. I added "propertyName:'LAND,DATUM'" to the L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js. It now shows these two variables in the popup, but also fid. How can I exclude a field? Is it possible?

Comment: with Freemarker-Templates that's easy to realize.Otherwise you can use css to set the first child of every row to display:none.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! If I understand it correctly to use the Freemarker-Templates I have to change files on the server directly. But what if I use other geoservers not handled from my own server? In this case CSS seems to be the better choice, right? Would you mind (as I have no clue how to do it) to my [Github](https://github.com/hoge6b01/WMSPopup.git) and tell me how to change the CSS (if possible shouldn't display the headline as well). Thank you very much

Comment: that's right. for the css-cheat have a look at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/268fd3023199a3611784

Comment: Very nice. Thanks you so much. Works! (now I'll need to find out how to fix that if no feature is selected no empty popup shows up. should be the next question. thanks

Comment: a quick-and-dirty-workaround is to check the text-length of the response...something like if(content.length>658){ // show popup} else { } but perhaps a question on SE will give you a even nicer solution ;)

Comment: Well, seems like finding a nicer solution isn't that [easy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139363/no-popup-on-map-if-no-feature-is-selected). Regarding the quick-and-dirty workaround: where do I have to put your mentioned lines? thanks

Comment: in your callback-function: "success: function(data) { "  ... there it's probably data.length or data.text.length what you have to check

Comment: The two steps described in http://apps.csdila.ie.unimelb.edu.au/index.php/how-to-enable-cors-on-geoserver/ helped me to get rid of the cross-domain issue.