# OpenLayers WFS problem

Tags: openlayers-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems with OpenLayers and WFS - proxy.cgi issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/problems-with-openlayers-and-wfs-proxy-cgi-issues)

I have a problem with a simple OpenLayers web page. I have two layers, first one is a WMS layer and work perfectly on QGIS and OpenLayers but the second WFS layer (tasmania_road) works on QGIS but it doesn't work on OpenLayers. I simply show two layer with  WFS tasmania_road on top of the WMS layer. My code shown below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function init() {  
            OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('rcp1_map');
            var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    { layers: 'basic' }
                ); 

            var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                    featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                })
            });

            map.addLayer(wms);
            map.addLayers([wms, layer]);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(146.7, -41.8), 6);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="rcp1_map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine for me, once I do the following two:

1. Use the full OpenLayers.js file.
2. Use a properly configured proxy.

Have you done this on your side?

My Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function init() {

        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                145.19754, -43.423512,
                148.27298000000002, -40.852802
            );
            var options = {
                controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()],
                maxExtent: bounds,
                maxResolution: 0.0120134375000001,
                projection: "EPSG:4326",
                units: 'degrees'
            };

        OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy_Open.cgi?url=";
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('rcp1_map', options);
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                { layers: 'basic' }
            ); 

        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url:  "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
            })
        });

        map.addLayers([wms, layer]);
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(146.7, -41.8), 2);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks i use postgresql for database which install on the server and i install geoserver on my computer and i develop my application with visual studio 2012 web forms i do my proxyhost :  OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/Proxy.aspx?url="; but still wms layer work perfetcly but wfs layer dont display

Comment: @CanAlperOzturk You first need to make sure that the proxy.cgi works. Without it you will not be able to access the WFS service.

Comment: how can i sure about proxy.cgi file. i find example http://www.mentby.com/Group/openlayers-users/vecor-layer-with-wfs-protocol-now-show-feature.html
wfs problem because of proxy. i dont know how to configure this proxy

Comment: @CanAlperOzturk Please look at this Answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2528/442